# Multivariable Calculus - Cylindrical Solid over a shifted disk region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

Need to find the cylindrical coordinates for the solid that lies under $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and above the region $(x-1)^2+y^2\leq 1$

Then use a triple integral to find the volume.

I don't understand how to convert the coordinates without symmetry about the z axis.

Comment: You know that the origin is not, in any way, a special place, right? You can just move it. Make the origin of your cylindrical coordinates be $(1,0,0)$. Place the $z$ axis in the middle of the second region. It will change what the equations look like, but I think that it overall will be a lot easier to integrate.

Comment: @Arthur but since the solid over the region is centered over (0,0) wouldn't that mess up my answer for the volume? Would the bounds still be 0<=z<=4-r^2, 0<=r<=1, 0<=theta<=2pi?

Comment: No, the first equation would get messier as the second equation gets easier. This is true. They do not have the same axis of symmetry, so it's impossible to find an origin that makes them both nice. But I still think that overall, the final calculations will be easier.

Comment: @Arthur I'm still lost on how to complete the problem, any chance you could help me find the bounds for the coordinates please? I think that would make the integral easy to find

Answer (score 0):

Moving the origin to $(1,0,0)$ decreases the $x$-coordinate by $1$. So for the equations to still describe the same surfaces / regions (they should stay where they are and not move along with our origin; if they did, moving the origin would be pointless), we have to substitute $x\mapsto x+1$. This gives us $z=4-(x+1)^2-y^2$ and $(x+1-1)^2+y^2\leq 1$. Tidying up and rewriting to polar form, we have
$$
z=4-r^2-2r\cos\theta -1\\
r^2\leq1
$$
This means the integration bounds on $r$ and $\theta$ are both constant (as long as $z$ is the innermost integration variable), and the integral should be rather straight-forward.

As a side note, you are missing a bottom bound on your integration region. As it stands, it is a cylinder with a paraboloid top, stretching infinitely far down. Is it, perhaps, meant to be $z\geq0$?

Answer (score 0):

If we take usual cylindrical coordinates, then you'll have $r-2\cos \phi \leqslant 0$, which gives on one hand curve for $r(\phi)$ and on another hand restriction $\cos \phi \geqslant 0$, which is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ as one possibility. So integral will be
$$\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{2\cos \phi}\int\limits_{0}^{4-r^2}\,d\phi dr dz$$

But if we take "shifted" cylindrical coordinates with $x=1+r\cos \phi$, then exactly now for $\phi$ will not be restrictions
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{3-r^2-2r\cos \phi }\,d\phi dr dz$$
Jacobian same for both cases.